# postfix skip spam checks for authorized SMTP

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, spam, amavis

Is there any way to configure postfix to skip spam/antivirus checks for those smtp connections that are SMTP-AUTH'ed? I would like to keep all the standard checks for external smtp traffic, but for my local users sending emails I would like to skip the antispam/antivirus checks.

My configuration has Postfix + Amavisd + SpamAssassin + clamav in pretty much standard configuration.

Thanks in advance.
MR

Answer (score 1):

In the main.cf, set

```
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining,permit_sasl_authenticated,check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/content_filter.pcre
```

Do not set content_filter= in main.cf!

/etc/postfix/content_filter.pcre should be something like:

```
/^/ FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

Do not forget to run

```
postmap /etc/postfix/content_filter.pcre
```

master.cf should be something like:

```
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -   n -   -  smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
smtp-amavis unix -      -       n       -       16       lmtp
    -o lmtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o lmtp_send_vforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
```

Hope this helps. See http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html for further info.

Answer (score 0):

In your main.cf file, assuming you have your spam filters in a `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` (or `smtpd_data_restrictions`/`smtpd_something_restrictions`), add `permit_sasl_authenticated` before anything else. This will accept authenticated users as early as possible in the process, without running any further checks. There is probably a way to have your spam/virus scanning to be included in the `smtpd_*_restrictions` lines using something like a `check_policy_service` entry, which will check against services defined in master.cf. I currently use this to run an external spf test against all mail, but I expect it will work for other checks.

Answer (score 0):

`pcre` files should not be *postmap'ed*.

Using content_filter in smtp port 25 only will disable it for smtp auth users, if port 25 is not used with sasl auth.

It's not very hard to configure.